# PowerBI: Unable to parse the response from the Azure ML Web Service

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-machine-learning-service

I created a time series experiment and a model in MS Azure Machine Learning.

That model is visible in PowerBI, but when trying to deploy it i get the following error:
Unable to parse the response from the Azure ML Web Service

I think it is due to the timestamp. When choosing a timestamp in BowerBI, I can only use numbers. No date format.

Did anyone solved this issue yet?

Comment: Is the model endpoint deployed works from command line?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to these documentation links about permissions and ensuring that the deployed AzureML model has appropriate swagger metadata available for consumption in Power BI.

Tutorial: [Consume an Azure Machine Learning model in Power BI - Azure Machine Learning | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-aml-integrate)